# CSS how to "look through" a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I have 4 html div's in total. Please see the image below:

[image]

I want to have 2 **draggable div**'s(blue with %20 opacity) which will reveal the intersection area with the underlying div.

[image]

I first thought about:

1. Creating 2 `img` elements named as div3 / div4 and assigning same `background-image` as div2.
2. Getting `cursor position` with javascript, for example with `event.clientX`
3. Offset div3 and div4 `background-position` according to `cursor position`

However, when I try to transform div3 and div4, `background-image` will be distorted and they won't have the mask effect anymore.

**How can I mask a div(1) with another div(2) on top of another div(3)?** I could use image-masking but it won't be dynamic anymore. With a div, I can dynamically change info in the div.

Edit: My example code is below. Please see the distortion of small div's backgrounds when using css transform property. I'm trying to make a "window" div. I won't include javascript drag code as this question is about div properties.

```css
.main {
                position: absolute;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1266810/pexels-photo-1266810.jpeg);
                background-size: 300px;
            }
            /*Images from https://www.pexels.com/photo/scenic-view-of-mountains-during-dawn-1266810/*/
            .secret {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: orange;
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                animation: loop 3s 0s infinite;
            }
            .lookthrough {
                position: absolute;
                width: 70px;
                height: 70px;
                background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1266810/pexels-photo-1266810.jpeg);
                background-size: 300px;
            }
            .example1 {
                left: 80px;
                top: 40px;
                background-position: -80px -40px;
                animation: stackoverflowexample 3s 0s infinite;
            }
            .example2 {
                left: 160px;
                top: 180px;
                background-position: -160px -180px;
                animation: stackoverflowexample 4s 0s infinite;
            }
            @keyframes loop {
                0% { opacity: 0; }
                50% { opacity: 1; }
                100% { opacity: 0; }
            }
            @keyframes stackoverflowexample {
                0% { transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg); }
                50% { transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg); }
                100% { transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg); }
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <div class="main"><div class="secret"></div></div>
        <div class="lookthrough example1">I need content here</div>
        <div class="lookthrough example2">I need content here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any code you want to share so we can all look where you at?

Comment: _“when I try to transform div3 and div4, background-image will be distorted”_ — How does that happen? Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre]. We can’t debug code we can’t see.

Comment: This effect can be done easily with a canvas element.  See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfZ5C/) for an example. Move the mouse over the black mask to show the layer below. There are also many canvas [libraries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API#libraries) available that each have their own focus. Have a look at the [P5.js](https://p5js.org/) library for educators.

Answer (score 0):

Use masking plus CSS variables for positioning.

Have one div with the body without the guts plus two divs which act as the 'holes'.

The hole divs are the same size as the body without guts but their background image is the body with guts. They have their backgrounds masked with a certain size (10%x10% of the whole has been chosen here, but alter to fit what you want) in positions which are determined by CSS variables (--x and --y).

You of course need to set --x and --y for each 'hole' when the mouse is on it and moved, so you will be looking for the mouse events on each hole element.

Here's a simple snippet using two images to show the concept:

```js
//in here set up event listeners on hole1 and hole2 for the various mouse events
//and when you want to change the position of a hole set the --x and --y variables using hole1.style.setProperty('--x', xvalue) etc
```

```css
.beneath,
.hole1,
.hole2 {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.beneath {
  /* replace with the body which has no guts image */
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300);
}

.hole1,
.hole2 {
  /* replace with the body which has guts image */
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(black, black);
  -webkit-mask-size: 10% 10%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: var(--x) var(--y);
}

.hole1 {
  --x: 70%;
  --y: 30%;
}

.hole2 {
  --x: 50%;
  --y: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="beneath"></div>
<div class="hole1"></div>
<div class="hole2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example code! It looks so much like what I tried before this topic. If I try to animate your hole1 and hole2, the image is distorted. Is there any code to prevent transform property to alter background image? Please see my code snippet above.

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a different question. The original was to allow dragging of the two holes. Could you explain a bit more what you want from animation? Especially I see you have rotations now which make no sense to me! But in any case don’t seem to be related to dragging.